# PHP Readfile() fails to open: connection refused

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get to work a wordpress plugin that let the user view or download a file attached to a post, but apparently everything fails when the plugin calls the readfile() function to get the file.

```
pddesenzano.it [Tue Oct 15 03:48:09 2013] AH01215:
PHP Warning:  readfile(http://pddesenzano.it/luci/luci_dicembre2012.pdf) 
[<a href='function.readfile'>function.readfile</a>]: failed to open stream: 
Connection refused in /home/sites/[...]/class.wp-publication-archive.php on line 302
```

The file exists and is downloadable by manually pasting the url in the browser, I wonder why the connection is refused...

Further details: the file and the php script are on the same machine.

Comment: Are you the owner of 'http://pddesenzano.it'? 'cause if you are, your logs should have logged why, and if you're not, ask the one who is why your server is denied access.

Comment: I'm the owner, but the only log I have access to shows just that four lines.

Comment: Assuming the attachment and the PHP script are on the same system , you would need to specify a local path rather than http://

Comment: Thank you Uours! I did a quick str_replace on the uri and now everything works flawlessly!